# Importing Swift Files into other Swift Files in Xcode6

Tags: xcode, import, swift, xcode6

Let's say I have a file called myAppDelegate.swift and another called myWindowController.swift. How do I import myWindowController into myAppDelegate, because currently if I just type

```
    import myWindowController
```

It says that it can't recognize that module. What's the step-by-step process for importing swift files into other swift files in Xcode6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import swift files in the same target into each other. The import statement is used for importing entire modules, not individual files. `myWindowController` should be accessible from `myAppDelegate` without needing to import.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't get that. I overthought it. Thanks for answering my dumb question.